# Django + PyMySQL throws "MySQL server has gone away" after a couple of hours

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, pymysql

I have a module in my Django 1.6 app (Python3) that runs like a daemon but it's throwing this error after a couple of hours running:

> OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")

It seems that exist a flag in MySQL connection that autoreconnect called [`MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/auto-reconnect.html), should I set it? Where? I’m using PyMySQL connector (by running `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()` in the main `__init__.py`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to catch the error when it is thrown, and call [`django.db.connection.close()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) to reconnect.

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
...
try:
    function_that_uses_database_connection()
except OperationalError:
    connection.close()
    function_that_uses_database_connection()
```

I did not found a way to make it automatic, though, but it did the job.